# Relations of functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am doing an assignment and I want to make sure I understood my definitions can someone check my table and if I went wrong please tell me where and why.

Original question
Determine whether the relation R on the set of all real numbers is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, irreflecive, and/or transitive where $(x,y) \in R$ if and only if
$$(a) x+y=0\\
(b)x=\pm y \\
(c)x-y \in \Bbb Q\\
(d)x=2y
$$

$$
    \begin{matrix}
     & reflexive & symmetric & antisymmetric & irreflexive & transitive\\
    x+y=0 &  & x &  & x &  \\
    x=\pm y & x & x &  &  & \\
    x-y \in \Bbb Q & x & x &  &  & x\\
    x=2y &  &  & x & x\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: What is the underlying set of the relations? $\mathbb{R}$? $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: does the edit help

Comment: It seems ok to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of irreflexive I've always seen is that the relation NEVER holds on an object with itself.  Then the first and fourth are not irreflexive, since $0=2(0)$ and $0+0=0$.  If your book/class uses a different definition, then you're fine, however.

Comment: so none of these are reflexive and a and d remain not reflexive

Comment: The second and third are reflexive, but the first and fourth are neither reflexive nor irreflexive.

Comment: thanks I didn't think of the $(0,0)$ tuple

Comment: Yeah, a lot of people forget to check the possibility of zero.  Similarly, people forget to check the possibility of the empty set when dealing with sets.  Now you know!

Comment: Your second relation is also transitive: if $x = \pm y$ and $y = \pm z$ then $x = \pm z$. (This is an equivalence relation, whose equivalence classes look like $\{ x, -x \}$.)

Comment: Thanks both Clive and Hayden for the help